# How can I rearrange celery flower default columns?

Tags: celery, flower

I am using the following versions:

flower==0.9.3

celery==4.3.0

Which gives me the following display for a tasks page with several columns:

[image]

Each time I enter this page I end up rearranging the page to have columns in a different order and I change the ordering for the rows to be descending.

What I want to know is if there is some way to configure it to have the columns and rows in that order by default.  i.e. Name -> State -> args -> Result -> UUID descending instead of Name -> UUID -> State -> args -> Result ascending

I haven't been able to find any mention of this in the docs, is there a configuration I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there are no customizable column sorting in flower. According to the [comment](https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/463#issuecomment-653942096) of flower's owner on Github issues [Jul 6, 2020]:

> There are no plans to work on this feature at the moment until someone decides to contribute to the project.

But, there is a [merged](https://github.com/mher/flower/pull/1142/commits/182d68dc22c852660113d5c708c74c78ea14ede6) pull request into flower's master branch that makes flower show the recent tasks on top in tasks page [Ordered by Started DESC]. You can install the Development version in order to change the default sorting if it helps:

```
$ pip install https://github.com/mher/flower/zipball/master#egg=flower
```